# Where did the Dog-people come from?

Tags: dragon-ball

In Dragon-ball there are numerous dog-people, one of which is the king of the world

[image]

There were other dog-people in the anime episode [Plight of the children](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Plight_of_the_Children).  One of the orphans was a dog person, and one of the police was a dog person.

Where did they all come from?  Did someone, one day, breed with a dog, thus spawning this race of Dog-people?

Comment: I think they are alien. Because in dragon ball universe earth is full of too many alien species.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Dragon Ball universe Animals are different form our earth animals. Some of then can talk and even walk on two legs.Take Puar and Oolong as an example. Its never explained that why some dogs on Dragon Ball universe act like normal dog and some act as human. Not only for the case of dog, there are other animals too which behave in the same way.

[Here](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Animal) is a link for the different species of animal appears in Dragon Ball Universe.

Its my own assumption that they can be alien on Dragon Ball universe from different planet. But there is no official words.

Or it may be a plot hole that some animals talk and some can't.

Comment: My personal theory is that it stems from the first wish made on the Dragon Balls - somewhere in the manga, it eludes to a dog that gathered them up, and wished to be ruler of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Dragon Ball was originally based of [Son Wukong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Wukong) the monkey king. The story involves several animals walking and talking like humans (of course including the monkey king, Son Wukong).

Answer (score 0):

That is due to it starting as a non serious manga for kids. It doesn't have any more meaning or interest that a comical one. For all respects these creatures are considered humans (note that Oolong and Puar are different).