# What happened to all the talking animals in Dragon Ball?

Tags: dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball

I remember Dragon Ball used to have lots of talking, humanoid foxes and the like. Then suddenly, in Dragon Ball Z, the only talking animals I remember are Oolong and Puar.

Is there any explanation for this or is it just a case of author discontinuing an idea?

Comment: For reference.. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2799/where-did-the-dog-people-come-from

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are still talking animals in Dragon Ball Z, in the episode [Plight of the children](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Plight_of_the_Children), the police officer is an animal, and some of the children are too.

Also, near the end of the Cell Saga, you had a cut to the King of the Earth (a dog), commenting on how much adult Goku, looked like the child Goku who killed King Piccolo.

---

But the number of talking animals did indeed get reduced.

It kinda goes with the direction Dragon Ball was taking.  It was moving away from being a fanciful, light-hearted comedy to a more serious fighting shonen, and the talking animals fit less and less to the story.

Comment: Which is sad, because the talking animal people in Dragon Ball were *awesome*.

Answer (score 3):

In Dragon Ball, [17%  of the population of earth are animals](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Animal#Overview). Even the king of earth is a blue dog. The reason they stopped showing them is because DBZ was mainly set in places like the South City and Ginger Town. Those were mainly populated by humans because animals are only found in the more city-like places, like the West City (That's where the World Tournament takes place and where Capsule Corp is).

Comment: Where did you get taht 17% figure?

Comment: Akira toriama hade an interview and it was said also it was calculated by the people who helped make it and its on Wikipedia

Comment: Put a link to the wikipedia page and I'll give you meaningless virtual points.

Comment: Well, look at that, I found it: http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Animal#Overview